# Как отключить сортировку при клике по столбцу в DataGridView?

Tags: c#

При щелчке по a1(или по другим названиям столбца) меняется порядок(показано на скрине), как его отключить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `DataGridView.Columns[i].SortMode` должен вам помочь

Answer (score 3):

На [SOeN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965304/disable-sorting-when-clicking-datagridview-column-header) в своё время давали ответ, с красивыми картинками

> You can disable auto sort for each and every individual cells in your DataGridView:
>   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

prabhuK2k(С)